# How can I save application settings in a VB .NET application?

Tags: vb.net

I made a projet a month ago in C# where I used application settings to save data. This time, I'm making a project in VB .NET where I need to store data. I have a textbox where the user input a certain key and if he gets it right, it sets a setting to true. Here's the code.

```
 Public Class Form4
  Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
      If TextBox1.Text = ("CF4A438C1F68D" Or "7552B2C629D11" Or "9C9C94A73141A" Or "7EE3998DAB3D3" Or "FC4DABC9CA7EA" Or "FDEE4B1F2C113" Or "D773E97B47531" Or "AABBBF181D39A" Or "36F37B39D19A5") Then
          Properties.Settings.Default.ActivatedVersion = True
          Properties.Settings.Default.Save()
      End If
  End Sub
End Class
```

Unfortunately, when I write Properties, it doesn't work. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In VB, you use `My.Settings` rather than `Properties.Settings.Default`.

Also, you don't necessarily need to call `Save` explicitly as it will happen automatically, by default, when the application exits. It won't happen if the application crashes but, if you have done the right thing and handled the `UnhandledException` event, the application will not crash, even if an unhandled exception is thrown.

Comment: Just note that, when I said that settings get saved automatically at shutdown, that is actually the default behaviour but you can turn that off in the project properties if you want to for some reason.